# Regular expressions in scala

Tags: validation, scala, functional-programming, expression

I am relatively new to Scala and I have been working on some school projects and it was all good :) , but right now I'm stuck with a regular expression validator. This program has to find out if a string can be generated by a regular expression, for instance: `"ad"` can be generated by the regular expression `"(a|b)(d)"`. In my implementation this works like this:

```
def exp: Exp = Concat(Opcion(Simple("a"), Simple("b")),Simple("d"))`

exp.eval("ad")  // returns true`
```

I'd like to know if there is a better way to accomplish my objective in the functional way. The current implementation is highly inefficient, and also when trying to program kleene closures and positive closures this become very complex.

This is what I have done so far:

```
abstract class Exp{  
  def eval(exp: String): Boolean =  this match{
    case Simple(a)    => a == exp
    case Opcion(a, b) => a.eval(exp) || b.eval(exp)
    case Concat(a, b) => a.concat(b).eval(exp)    
    case COpcional(a) => Opcion(Simple(""), a).eval(exp)
  }

  private def concat(exp: Exp): Exp = this match{
    case Simple(a)    => exp match{
        case Simple(b)  => Simple(a + b) 
        case _          => Concat(Simple(a), exp)
    }  
    case Opcion(a, b) => Opcion(a.concat(exp), b.concat(exp))
    case Concat(a, b) => a.concat(b.concat(exp))
    case COpcional(a) => Opcion(Simple("").concat(exp), a.concat(exp))
  }
}`

case class Simple(valor: String) extends Exp`

case class Opcion(e1: Exp, e2: Exp) extends Exp`

case class Concat(e1: Exp, e2: Exp) extends Exp`

case class COpcional(e1: Exp) extends Exp`

case class CPositiva(e1: Exp) extends Exp`

case class CKleene(e1: Exp) extends Exp`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me if the assignment is to verify that a string is matched by a regular expression "by any means available" or specifically to implement a basic regex matching algorithm?

If it's the former, the library can do that trivially easily.

If it's the latter, you need to learn about NFAs and their relationship to regular expressions, how to parse REs (hint: parsing REs requires a pushdown automata) and how to "execute" the resulting NFA against an input string. This is not exactly elementary computer science. Nor is it graduate level, but definitely not dead simple.